# Response to "Would you not do it?"

Tags: questions, negation

If posed with the subject question, given that I will not do the action in question, then what is the correct answer

> No, I will not do it.

or

> Yes, I will not do it.

#1 sounds better to me, but #2 is more logical. #1 sounds somewhat paradoxical in context of the question.

Comment: _No, I would not do it._

Comment: The more interesting question is what to say if you *will* do it... neither "No, I will do it"  or "Yes, I will do it" seems to work.

Comment: Er...I scratch my head and equivocate.

Comment: I would always say #2, but I always restate the question anyway, so whether I say "yes" or "no" is pretty much irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the first one as "No" asserts negativity. The following [Wikipedia post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes-no_question#How_such_questions_are_answered) could be helpful here:

> According to [Grimes](http://books.google.com/books?id=vnZN19-acqoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Joseph+Evans+Grimes&source=bl&ots=DyP6Au8Fi-&sig=QORr42J0z5ApEDIsj-75CRFvNvg&hl=en&ei=uLuZTPDtKc-ysAb-842KDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false), the answer
>   "yes" asserts a positive answer and
>   the answer "no" asserts a negative
>   answer, irrespective of the form of
>   the question. But in fact simple "Yes"
>   or "No" word sentence answers to
>   yes-no questions can be ambiguous in
>   English. For example, a "Yes" response
>   to the question "You don't beat your
>   wife?" could mean either "Yes, I don't
>   beat my wife." or "Yes, I do beat my
>   wife." depending from whether the
>   respondent is replying with the
>   truth-value of the situation, or is
>   replying to the polarity used in the
>   question. This ambiguity does not
>   exist in languages that employ echo
>   answers. In the Welsh language, for
>   example, the response "ydw" ("I am")
>   has no such ambiguity when replying to
>   a question.

Comment: Midhat's logic is used in some languages, like Korean and Japanese.  Responding "yes" in those languages means "your question as written/spoken is true" and "no" means "your question as written/spoken" is false.  But in English we do as Mehper describes.