# Did English ever have a word for 'yes' for negative questions?

Tags: etymology, history, questions, old-english, middle-english

The Germans have *doch* and the French have *si* as a word that means "yes" in response to a negative question, such as:

> Don't you want some ice-cream?
>   Yes [I do]!

In English, we only have *yes* (as far as I know) and further clarification is required in order to be unambiguous.

Did we ever have such a word in English and, if so, what happened to it? If not, given the French and Germanic influences on English, any idea why not?

Comment: This is exactly what [I was asking](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28530/how-to-answer-a-negative-question-without-ambiguity).

Comment: So it is... voting to close as a duplicate

Comment: @Gigili, @Dancrumb: well, this question is not answered in detail in the linked question. I don't think they're really duplicate: one concerns Modern English, the other historical Englishes.

Comment: As a side comment, as far as I know, the English word corresponding to the German "doch" is "though", even though nowadays they have a different meaning.

Comment: I've heard Scottish and Irish friends use the word 'so' as follows: "You didn't lock the door"
"I did so."

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Such words existed in Early Modern English (roughly 1450–1650), and they were… **yes** and **no**. However, the answers to positive questions at the time were *yea* and *nay*. You could summarize their use as such:

> - Will he not go? — Yes, he will.
> - Will he not go? — No, he will not.
> - Will he go? — Yea, he will.
> - Will he go? — Nay, he will not.

---

It is well detailed in this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_and_no#The_English_four-form_and_two-form_systems) (which I first read in [an answer by z7sg](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28530/how-to-answer-a-negative-question-without-ambiguity/28531#28531) earlier today):

> Whilst Modern English has a two-form system for affirmatives and negatives, Early Modern English in fact had a four-form system, comprising the words **yea**, **nay**, **yes**, and **no**. [...] The answers to **positively framed questions** (*"Will he go?"*) were **yea** and **nay**, whilst the answers to **negatively framed questions** (*"Will he not go?"*) were **yes** and **no**. This subtle grammatical nicety of Early Modern English is recorded by Sir Thomas More in his critique of William Tyndale's translation of the New Testament into Early Modern English.

---

<sup>As you noted Modern French, as other languages, has a three-form system where both negative answers are the same (*oui* is the affirmative answer to a positive question, *si* is the affirmative answer to a negative question, and *non* is the negative answer to any type of question).</sup>