# Why say "nay" when you could say "no"

Tags: etymology, negation

I am curious as to why "nay" replaces the simple unequivocal "no" in the context of voting.

My research in Merriam-Webster tells me that "nay" means "no" (not the other way around) and the first known use of "nay" appeared in 1400s. Since the use of "no" existed before 1400 and the word remains to be used afterward, why would "nay" become the preferred choice of word when it comes to voting. Any idea?

Comment: Not in the UK's House of Commons, where those in favour of a motion say 'Aye', and those against say . . . 'No'.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: "The eyes to the left... the nose to the right..."

Answer (score 23):

[Apparently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_and_no#The_Early_English_four-form_system), Early Modern English had a four-form system of *yes* and *no*, where *yes* and *no* were used to answer negatively phrased questions (e.g., "Will he not go?") whilst *yea* and *nay* were used to answer positively phrased questions (e.g., "Will he go?"). Since the sort of questions voted on by assemblies are positively phrased, I'd imagine that the legislative use of *yea* and *nay* is a relic of this earlier usage.

Comment: Hugely related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28581/did-english-ever-have-a-word-for-yes-for-negative-questions

Comment: Indeed it is! The comparison to the situation in French and German is very much worth thinking about.

Answer (score 4):

Section 7 of the US Constitution specifies that Congress must vote on bills using Yea and Nay, and so it does.  That specification instead of Yes and No still had  meaning in formal matters the 1700s per the four-form Yea/Yes/Nay/No system mentioned by Branimir Ćaćić, even though Yea and Nay were by then falling out of use in common speech.

Answer (score 0):

The truth is a little more complex. It have to do with the fact that English is a compound language, created by the two main waves of invasions that happened between the 9th and the 11th century.
Basically English is a combination of French and Danish. No comes from French "no" while Nay comes from Danish "nej"
It is an aberration that French is the dominant form for a simple word like a negation, the norm is that the complicated words like "government" comes from French, while simple words like "cat" comes from Danish.
In other cases the two root languages are used simultaneously like with freedom and liberty.
But to be short, nay was introduced into English in the 9th century, while no arrived in the 11th

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The OED's first cite for "nay" is c. 1175; it suggests an Old Scandinavian origin, but not specifically Danish.