# Synonym of No in an escalating context

Tags: synonyms, orthography

What is the exact spelling of the word pronounced [nei], when you mean to escalate your point by stating something, [nei] something with greater power ?

Example: With this book you shall learn, [nei] understand the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Nay](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nay)

> or rather (used to emphasize a more appropriate word than one just
> used) ‘permission to build the superstore will take months, nay years’ - OLD

Regarding the etymology of the word:

> Early Modern English had a four-form system of yes and no, where yes
> and no were used to answer negatively phrased questions (e.g., "Will
> he not go?") whilst yea and nay were used to answer positively phrased
> questions (e.g., "Will he go?"). Since the sort of questions voted on
> by assemblies are positively phrased, I'd imagine that the legislative
> use of yea and nay is a relic of this earlier usage. - [Why say "nay" when you could say "no"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96540/why-say-nay-when-you-could-say-no)

Comment: "Or rather" that's how I know it in this context. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! I'll update my answer with that sense.