# Answering negative statements

Tags: negation, answers

> You aren’t supposed to be here.

Yes, I am or No, I am? Also yes, I am not or no, I am not?

> It isn’t raining.

Yes, it is or yes, it isn’t?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28530/how-to-answer-a-negative-question-without-ambiguity?rq=1 and https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28581/did-english-ever-have-a-word-for-yes-for-negative-questions/28582#28582

Answer (score 0):

#### If you are concisely *disagreeing,* use "Yes, I am"; "Yes, it is"

If the question uses a negative verb, and you are answering briefly and contradicting the assertion, it is conventional to say "Yes," and the positive verb, as shown above.

#### If you are concisely *agreeing* with the statement, you can just say "No"

This would mean that you are accepting that you are not supposed to be here, or that it is not raining.

#### If you are agreeing and going to give a longer remark or explanation, you can use *either* "Yes" or "No".

Both of these are correct. It is the "but" that indicates that you are accepting the speaker's negative statement as correct.

> Yes, but I had to come in here because there is a riot outside.

> No, but I had to come in here because there is a riot outside.

Similarly, both of these are correct:

> Yes, but the forecast is for rain, so I do need my umbrella.

> No, but the forecast is for rain, so I do need my umbrella.