# Have you not had lunch yet? Yes

Tags: differences

In English, *yes* here means "Yes, I have had lunch".

Answering "no" will mean "No, I have not had lunch".

(My question isn't about how to answer this simple question)

However, in some languages, *yes* actually means "Yes, your statement is correct; I have not had lunch". Answering no would actually mean "No, your statement is incorrect; I have already had lunch".

I wonder what such a difference is called? Such difference can lead to mis-communication, as I have personally experienced. Is there any background information for the two approaches?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to answer a negative question without ambiguity?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28530/how-to-answer-a-negative-question-without-ambiguity)

Comment: I have already stated I am not seeking answer to **HOW** to answer this question. I already know **HOW** to answer it correctly without causing confusion. My question focus on the DIFFERENCE of approaches across different languages.

Comment: Reminds me of those times when I ask my wife either/or type questions like, "Do you want fork or a spoon?" and she replies, "Yes." :)

Comment: So to clarify, you're looking for the name of the miscommunication issue itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's just a matter of [meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meaning_%28linguistics%29) as opposed to the literal interpretation of words and syntax.

In English, the inclusion of *not* in OP's question simply signifies that the speaker *expects the other person has* **not** *had lunch*. But the meaning of the question isn't changed by this additional information, so there's no need for the response to be inverted because of it.

[Do you not understand?](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do%20you%20not%20understand&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Comment: English is my second language, and in my native language, answering "Yes" to "Do you not understand?" would actually mean "Yes what you said is correct, I do **NOT** understand". While in English, you ought to say "Yes" meaning "Yes I understand". As English is my second language I personally find it very unnatural, but I do understand the reason behind it. What I am curious about it why does such difference across languages exist?

Comment: @Gapton: These cross-cultural differences are most important in the building of international social relationships. It's like the meaning of nodding (can mean yes or no according to culture) in the field of gestures.  
Are you aware that a [Culture exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/17087/culture-exchange) is under commitment on Stack Exchange Area 51? We can ask the question there if it gets created.

Comment: @Gapton: Would you mind telling us what your first language is, Gapton?

Comment: @Barrie: I also thought it might be more a cultural difference at first, but once I'd written the first sentence of my answer it seemed to me it's just an idiomatic quirk of English that we can drop *not* into the phrasing of questions like this without altering the basic query which we expect to be answered. Maybe many other languages simply don't support such usage.

Comment: Actually its more complicated. You see, my first language is Chinese (strictly, Cantonese and Mandarin). You may be aware of how different Chinese and English are, but it may still surprise you that there is difference between a simple "Yes". Our "Yes" is actually closer to English's "Correct" (No = Wrong). When we say "Yes" we mean "Correct", thus implying "What you just said is correct". In English, "Yes" means "Positive", while it is awkward to answer "Positive" most of the time, the true meaning is indeed "Positive". If you contrast "Positive" and "Correct", you will see the difference.

Comment: In English (more accurately, in the [Vulcan-English](http://www.angelfire.com/oh/quotations/startrek/originalstartrek/spock.html) of Star Trek's Doctor Spock), we use the word **affirmative** to mean *Your statement exactly as phrased is* *true*.