# How can I answer back?

Tags: grammar, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to answer a negative question without ambiguity?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28530/how-to-answer-a-negative-question-without-ambiguity)

If someone ask you this question 
 "Don't you have exam? " 
 how can I answer back using only (Yes and No). 
that's funny - I  used to answer "Yes" then he/she ask me again  "when is your exam?" 
that's confuse me because I answered "Yes" that mean I don't have Exam but she get it in wrong way. If I answer "No" then it will mean I have exam, but I don't have exam.

So which is right answer "Yes" or "No" ?

Hope my question will make sense!
Thanks