# Answering a negatively-expressed question

Tags: questions, negation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to answer a negative question without ambiguity?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28530/how-to-answer-a-negative-question-without-ambiguity)

> 2). Didn't we park on the C level?
>   (A) Yes, I sure thought we did.
>   (B) No, we'll park on the D level.
>   (C) Yes, we didn't park on level C.

Which is the best answer to a negative-polarity question, please?

Answer (score 2):

Native English speakers tend to avoid answers like (C), especially if -- as usual -- the explanation clause is left off and the answer is reduced to only *Yes*.

The rule is that, for the most part (i.e, I can't think of an exception, so I'm hedging), [Negative](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) *Yes/No* questions (not, btw, [*"negative-polarity"*](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf)) get answered *Yes* or *No* just as if they were affirmative questions. Since logic doesn't deal with questions, the negation has no logical force.

It's just there as a conventional marker to express the speaker's belief that the answer should be *Yes*. Negative questions are often used in rhetorical questions not meant to be answered by anyone but the speaker -- "Now, wouldn't this look better over there? ... Yes, it definitely does." Language never lets a useless convention go to waste.

So, (C) is not right, (A) is fine, and (B) doesn't make any sense, since it says *we'll park* instead of *we parked*; with that correction, though, it's fine too. And just *Yes* for (A) and *No* for (B) are fine and normal, too -- though it's always safer to clarify an answer if there's any possibility of doubt.

Comment: *Negative-polarity* was me. Feel free to improve the question.

Comment: Well, then, the correction was due for you. Feel free to learn the distinction :-) NPIs are a negative phenomenon, but only one of many. Negation is a **BIG** phenomenon. From the first link: "Negative utterances are a core feature of every system of human communication and of no system of animal communication. Negation and its correlates – truth-values, false messages, contradiction, and irony – can thus be seen as defining characteristics of the human species."