# Looks like it's not a game: Yes, it does: So... does it look like it's a game?

Tags: questions

*I posted this question as a non-English mother tongue.*

I've seen a conversation as below (comments on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OCU862nVpJ0):

> A: 8:56 **Looks** like **it's not** a game!
>
> B: yeah, it does.

So, did B agree to A or not? I am a bit confused with two interpretations.

1. Yeah, it **looks** like it's not a game
2. Yeah, it looks like **it's** a game

I learned to say 'yes' or 'does' for a positive response and 'no' or 'doesn't' for a negative response.

So, if B said 'does' to '**looks**', the answer is (1.), but if he said 'does' against '**it is not**', then the answer is (2.)

One thing is that, 'does' cannot come after *be* verb, so I think (1.) is more probable.

However, since I am not the native, I want to hear the answer from the native or an English expert.

Comment: In English it is very difficult to answer a negative questions without ambiguity or confusion. The most detailed analysis I have seen on this site is here :  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28530/how-to-answer-a-negative-question-without-ambiguity

Comment: That is a really confusing case, since you have two verbs. It's lucky one of them is *to be*. But consider *"Looks like it doesn't work right,"* where *"yes, it does"* and *"no it doesn't"* are both completely ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in your analysis of what verb the word "does" refers to.

It would be considered wrong in standard English to say "it does be a game" or "it does not be a game", so the "does" of the answer does not refer to the verb "to be".

And it's fine to say "it does look like it's a game" or "it does not look like it's a game", so the "does" of the answer refers to the verb "to look".

But there is still the ambiguity of whether the answer is intended to imply **(1)** "yeah, it does look like **it's not a game**", or **(2)** "yeah it does look like **it's a game**".

If the tone of the answer sounds positive, open, or otherwise agreeable, then ***B*** is probably agreeing with ***A***, and intending choice **1**, which is an acceptance of the sentence that was offered.

On the other hand, if the tone of the answer sounds defensive, indignant, or otherwise contrary, then ***B*** is probably disagreeing, and intending choice **2**. This would appear to be logically inconsistent, because it's affirmative but it does not contain the sentence that was actually offered by ***A***. Nonetheless, it's still possibly what ***B*** intends.

Without tone of voice, I would tend to assume the logically consistent answer, so choice **1**. That's the sense I get from reading the comment you're referring to, so yeah, it does look like it's not a game. But generally there's no sure way to tell in a case like this, without clarification.

Comment: @Lawrence: +1 for reminding me I could just refer to them as A and B. That simplifies things a bit. :-)