# Confirming and Agreeing

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, questions

As I was told to ask a new question, I better do. :)

On the Internet I read the folowing conversation:
Question: Do people say No to mean they are in agreement with negative statements?
Answer: We aren't using "no" to agree, we are using "no" to CONFIRM a negative statement.

So my question is does that mean:
Mother: We are not buying a new car.
Father: No. (he confirms) / Father: Yes. (he agrees)

But somehow I would think if the father agrees or confirms he would buy the new car? So why does he say yes if he agrees? I always thought the father would say yes if he would like to buy the car.

Somehow even in the threads that have been marked as duplicates I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: If you want it to be answered, read the linked duplicate question and come back with what you understand and what you don't with your own research.

Comment: I read it, not only your linked thread, and that is why I don't understand why no is for confirmation and yes for agreement to negative questions, as I would think no is for confirmation/agreement and yes for disagreement/no confirmation. But somehow no seems to be for confirmation and yes for agreement?

Comment: English speakers ***do not*** use "yes" to agree to negative statements. We use "that's right" or "correct" to agree with negative statements.  I think you misunderstood what the conversation was trying to say.

Comment: I found it here: http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/239355-Agreeing-with-Negative-Statements?p=1251564&viewfull=1#post1251564

Comment: The user seems trustable, as it seems to be a moderator.

Comment: Then, why didn't you ask the question there? Why do you ask here?

Comment: You misunderstood the conversation. Read it more closely.

Comment: I read it times and times, can you please help me? I asked it here cause the thread there seemed to be closed. And I am a long time silent reader here.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain ***exactly*** what you don't understand about it. It's a relatively long thread, and I don't believe the moderator ever says that we use *yes* to agree with negative statements, something that you claim she does in your question.

Comment: We explain how to answer negative questions [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28530/how-to-answer-a-negative-question-without-ambiguity). Agreeing/disagreeing with negative statements works exactly the same way.

Comment: Yeah Peter, but I still do not understand why there a moderator says that "we aren't using "no" to agree, we are using "no" to CONFIRM a negative statement.". I read your linked thread as you use no to confirm AND agree.

Comment: I think they're trying to make a distinction between *confirm* and *agree*. If somebody says *so you're not going on vacation next week*, we don't say *no, I agree with you*, we say *no, I'm not going on vacation* or *no, I'm not*.

Comment: And all in all it is correct to say that we answer negative questions with no to confirm / agree and we answer negative questions with yes to disagree / to say it is wrong, correct?

Comment: Mother: "We are not buying a new car."  Father, "No, we are not."  or, Father:  "That's right, we are not."  Father would not say: "Yes, we are not."   That's the way it is.   See Peter Schor's statement above "English speakers do not use "yes" to agree to negative statements. We use "that's right" or "correct" to agree with negative statements. I think you misunderstood what the conversation was trying to say"

Comment: Yeah thank you, got that. So all in all it is correct to say that we answer negative questions with no to confirm / agree and we answer negative questions with yes to disagree / to say it is wrong, correct?

Comment: Or is it better to say we confirm with "no, we are not.", agree with "that's right, we are not." and disagree with "yes, we are buying a new car."?

Comment: "We are not going on a vacation this year.  We can't afford the time or the money."   "Oh, yes we are going on a vacation.  If I don't get out of here, I will go crazy."  the point of this long example is in real life, people always amplify to eliminate confusion and to make their point.

Comment: Yeah got that but still it seems like you disagree negative questions with "yes" and confirm/agree negative questions with no, so I wonder why the quoted part in my question says we don't agree negative questions with no.

Comment: If you want to avoid ambiguity don't answer with a single Yes/No answer. Elaborate with an additional statement: (*agreement*) No, we are not buying a car. OR (*confirmation*) Yes, you've understood correctly, we are not buying a car.  OR to contradict: "No, you've misunderstood, we ***are*** buying a car."

Comment: @Jim Thank you, but now you say you agree with "No, we are not buying a car.", but the quote in my question above says that "We aren't using "no" to agree, we are using "no" to CONFIRM a negative statement." So something is wrong there?

Comment: There is the very simple matter that can respond to virtually any question with an ambiguous answer.  This is doubly true when the question asks a negative -- "Are you not going to do X?"  A yes or no answer is simply insufficient, absent some other clues from the answerer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with responding to negative statements is that there are two ways of responding to them:

1. You can respond with respect to the underlying thought.
2. You can respond with respect to the veracity of the speaker's statement.

When given the statement, "We are not buying a new car" I can respond with,

1. "No" meaning, "No we're not buying a new car." - I am responding to the underlying thought.  And when we agree with the underlying negative statement we show agreement with a similarly constructed negative.
2. "No" meaning, "*No*, we ***are*** buying a new car." - I am responding with respect to the veracity of the statement and indicating that the statement is false- we are, in fact, buying a new car.
3. "Yes" meaning, "Yes, you are correct we are *not* buying a new car" - I am responding with respect to the veracity of the statement and indicating that the statement is true - we are *not* buying a new car.
4. "Yes" meaning, "*Yes*, we ***are*** [buying a new car]." - I am responding to the underlying thought and disagreeing or correcting the misunderstanding.

As can be seen here it is impossible to correctly interpret a one word, "yes/no" answer to a negative statement because it is ambiguous as to which way the respondent is answering. (Sometimes tone of voice and timing can help in spoken exchanges).
This is why native speakers, wishing to be as clear as possible, will often provide that second sentence with the appropriate elaboration. Or, if they don't, why questions like, "'No' we *are* or 'No' we *aren't*?" are often heard. (And similarly for "Yes").

What else can be done about it?
The questioner can also realize that they're setting themselves up for a possibly ambiguous answer and change the question:

1. "Are we buying a new car?"
2. "Did I hear that correctly? We are not buying a new car?"
   (Of course this isn't foolproof because the respondent can still answer the second question and not the first.)

The respondent can respond with

1. "You are correct" (We are not buying a new car)
2. "That's right."  (We are not buying a new car)
3. "Actually, we ***are*** buying a new car." - '*Actually*' is used to introduce a contradictory statement.
4. Precede the statement with 'fortunately' or 'unfortunately' depending on the "goodness" of the result:
      "Unfortunately, no, we have to keep the old one"
      "Fortunately, no, they were able to fix the old one and it should last for several more years."