# How do you answer tag questions with ", right?"?

Tags: questions

When you asked "You don't love me, right?": 
Which word is used to answer, "Right." or "Yes."?

If the answer is "Right":

--> Does "Right" mean "What you said is right, i.e., I don't love you.", doesn't it?

If the answer is "Yes":

--> Which does "Yes" mean, "Yes, what you said is right." or "Yes, I love you."?

Comment: Either way you're already in trouble.  Trying to pick the "right" word here is far less important than feeling what you're saying.

Comment: Never, ever, ever, answer a question about whether you love someone with a one-word answer. Either give a long and complete answer, or deny the presupposition and start over with a better question.

Comment: The fact that the question ends with ", right?" is not the problem. The problem is that the question is phrased as a negative.  General advice for negative questions: don't answer with just one word.  Give enough of a phrase to remove the ambiguity that the question raises.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to answer a negative question without ambiguity?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/28530/26083)

Comment: Maybe it isn't a question at all, but a statement: "You don't love me right." Not that that situation is any pleasanter to deal with.

Comment: Interesting fact by the way: in German we have the two answers "Ja" und "Doch" which both in English translate to "yes". "Ja", albeit weird as we usually confirm a negative question with "Nein" (no), means "Yes, you're right, I don't love you", while "Doch" means "Yes, I do love you".

Answer (score 1):

Q: "You don't love me, right?"

A1: "Right." This means I don't love you. Your statement of "You don't love me" is correct.

A2: "Yes." This is an unclear and unusual way of responding, but I would interpret it to mean that I don't love you.

A3: "Yes, I do!" This means I love you!

A4: "Wrong!" This means I love you! Your statement of "You don't love me" is wrong.

Comment: English Learner - please use an upvote, and the accept button - don't comment "thanks"

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for https://ell.stackexchange.com/.

The answer differs depending on the intent of the question.

For your specific example, "*You don't love me, right?*" implies that the asker thinks the answerer doesn't love them, and is either seeking confirmation or hoping to be contradicted. Answers might be "*No, I do love you*", "*I don't*", or "*That's right, I don't love you.*" Just answering "*Right*" would be considered very terse, and answering "*Yes*" would be unusual and ambiguous (see [How to answer a negative question without ambiguity?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28530/how-to-answer-a-negative-question-without-ambiguity)).

For a confirmatory question like "*Your house is by the sea, right?*", "*Right*" would be a very normal answer.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer and the site you showed me helped me a lot.